# Find index of all characters in text from textarea c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I want to get text data from textarea in view and find all indexes of character '{'. 
But it isn't find anything. Problem I think it text, because if i try this code in new string it works. How can i transform this text in a right way?

This is view

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AllText, 40, 100, new { @title = "Comment" })</p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
}
```

model

```
 public class TextCode
    {
        public string AllText{ get; set; }
    }
```

and controller

```
 public ViewResult Answer(TextCode Text) 
        {
            var newfile = Text.ToString();

            string pattern = "{";
           // string ggg = "newfile{newfile{newfile{{newfile{";
            IList<int> indeces = new List<int>();
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(newfile, pattern))
            {
                indeces.Add(match.Index);
            }
```

and indeces is empty in this case.

Comment: You sure that the value of the textarea is being bound to the `ViewResult`? - Have you tried to set a breakpoint and check the value of `Text`? - Please post the relevant code for the class `TextCode`.

Comment: If you step through your controller in the debugger, is the property `AllText` filled with the value from the form like you expect?  Also, I assume that the `ToString` method is overridden in the TextCode class to return the value of `AllText`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, problem in this value. How can I post it from model to controller in a right way?

Comment: The default MVC Model binder will attempt to match all properties of your model (in your case, the `TextCode` model) to form fields, query string values, etc.. based on its `name` html attribute.  If the name of the text area in the form (when you view source of the rendered page) does not match the name of the property in your model, then the value will not be passed to the controller.  If they are the same, it should be being passed for the `AllText` property of the `TextCode` class.  Consider changing the variable name from `Text` to something more descriptive for your controller parameter.